# How to find the coordinates where the altitude of a triangle intersects the base in 3 dimensions?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Assuming I know three completely random coordinates in 3d space that correspond with vertices of a triangle, how can I then find the point at which the altitude intersects the base? I know how to calculate the side lengths of the triangle and have an idea of how to solve my problem, but I become stuck when challenged with finding the height of the altitude.

Comment: What is your idea of how to solve this? Please do add it to your question. This will provide the necessary background based on which someone could answer your question.

Comment: If $AB$ is your base, $C$ the third point, take $(\vec {CA} + k\vec{AB})$ and calculate where it is orthogonal to $\vec {AB}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out myself a few hours after my initial post, my method is as follows.

In this example I'm assuming the base of the triangle to be AB

Firstly, point D can be defined as any point plus the vector connecting them. One point we already have is point A, meaning $$D=A+ \vec{AD}$$.

We can then find $\vec{AD}$ by scaling $\vec{AB}$ ($\vec{AB}=B-A$) by $\frac{AD}{AB}$. So, $$\vec{AD}=(\frac{AD}{AB})(\vec{AB})$$
So all that is needed now is the distance of the altitude and the distance of AB. AB we can figure out useing the following formula $$AB=\sqrt{\vec{AB.x}^2+\vec{AB.y}^2+\vec{AB.z}^2}$$
The distace of the altitude is all that is left to find. For this we know that altitude is equal to $2\frac{area}{base}$, in our case the base is AB and we are left to find the area of the triangle without the height, thankfully we have Herons Formula which gives us the area given 3 side lengths
$$s=\frac{AB+BC+CA}{2}$$
$$A=\sqrt{s(s-AB)(s-BC)(s-CA)}$$
By then plugging everything in we find point D

Answer (score 2):

Let $\vec{p}_0$ and $\vec{p}_1$ be the vertices at the base of the triangle, with $\vec{p}_2$ the vertex at apex.

Define $\hat{b}$ as the base unit vector,
$$\hat{b} = \frac{\vec{p}_1 - \vec{p}_0}{\left\lVert\vec{p}_1 - \vec{p}_0\right\rVert}$$
where $\lVert\vec{p}_1 - \vec{p}_0\rVert = \sqrt{(\vec{p}_1-\vec{p}_0)\cdot(\vec{p}_1-\vec{p}_0)}$.

If we project the vector from first base vertex to apex vertex, $(\vec{p}_2 - \vec{p}_0)$, to the base unit vector $\hat{b}$ (using vector dot product), we get the (signed) distance on the base to a point directly below the apex vertex. The distance between that point and the apex is the height $h$ of the triangle:
$$h = \left\lVert (\vec{p}_2 - \vec{p}_0) - \hat{b} ( \hat{b} \cdot (\vec{p}_2 - \vec{p}_0) \right\rVert$$
Substituting $\hat{b}$ we get
$$h = \left\lVert \vec{p}_2 - \vec{p}_0 - \frac{\left(\vec{p}_1 - \vec{p}_0\right)\left(\left( \vec{p}_1 - \vec{p}_0 \right)\cdot\left(\vec{p}_2 - \vec{p}_0 \right)\right)}{\left(\vec{p}_1 - \vec{p}_0\right)\cdot\left(\vec{p}_1 - \vec{p}_0\right)} \right\rVert$$

In pseudocode, a function that calculates the height given the base vertex coordinates `x0,y0,z0` and `x1,y1,z1` and the apex vertex coordinates `x2,y2,z2`, is

```
function triangle_height(x0,y0,z0, x1,y1,z1, x2,y2,z2):
    # x0,y0,z0   First base vertex 
    # x1,y1,z1   Second base vertex
    # x2,y2,z2   Apex vertex

    tmp0 = x1 - x0
    tmp1 = y1 - y0
    tmp2 = z1 - z0
    tmp3 = x2 - x0
    tmp4 = y2 - y0
    tmp5 = z2 - z0

    tmp6 = tmp0*tmp0 + tmp1*tmp1 + tmp2*tmp2
    if (tmp6 <= 0) then
        # Degenerate triangle; (x0,y0,z0) = (x1,y1,z1).
        # It is not a triangle, but a line (or a point).
        # This returns the length of the line,
        # or 0 if (x0,y0,z0) = (x1,y1,z1) = (x2,y2,z2).
        hh = tmp3*tmp3 + tmp4*tmp4 + tmp5*tmp5

    else
        tmp7 = (tmp0*tmp3 + tmp1*tmp4 + tmp2*tmp5) / tmp6

        # tmpx,tmpy,tmpz is the apex vector, perpendicular to base
        tmpx = tmp3 - tmp7 * tmp0
        tmpy = tmp4 - tmp7 * tmp1
        tmpz = tmp5 - tmp7 * tmp2

        hh = tmpx*tmpx + tmpy*tmpy + tmpz*tmpz
    end if

    return sqrt(hh)
```

The above pseudocode is hand-tuned from Maple `codegen` module output from the vector formula, adding the check. Although math says `tmp6` cannot be negative, it is *better practice* to check if it is nonpositive instead. You see, any floating-point comparison against an exact value is always suspect, even if the target value is zero.

---

The Wolfram Mathworld article on [3D Point-Line Distance](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html) mentions in passing an even simpler formula:

$$h = \frac{\left\lVert\left(\vec{p}_1 - \vec{p}_0\right)\times\left(\vec{p}_0 - \vec{p}_2\right)\right\rVert}{\left\lVert\vec{p}_1 - \vec{p}_0\right\rVert}$$

(Note the different numbering here, $2\gets 0$, $0\gets 1$, $1\gets 2$, compared to the Mathworld page.)

In pseudocode:

```
function triangle_height(x0,y0,z0, x1,y1,z1, x2,y2,z2):
    # x0,y0,z0   First base vertex 
    # x1,y1,z1   Second base vertex
    # x2,y2,z2   Apex vertex

    tmp0 = x1 - x0
    tmp1 = y1 - y0
    tmp2 = z1 - z0
    tmp3 = x0 - x2
    tmp4 = y0 - y2
    tmp5 = z0 - z2
    tmp6 = tmp0*tmp0 + tmp1*tmp1 + tmp2*tmp2
    if (tmp6 <= 0) then
        hh = tmp3*tmp3 + tmp4*tmp4 + tmp5*tmp5
    else
        tmp7 = tmp5*tmp1 - tmp2*tmp4
        tmp8 = tmp2*tmp3 - tmp5*tmp0
        tmp9 = tmp4*tmp0 - tmp1*tmp3
        hh = (tmp7*tmp7 + tmp8*tmp8 + tmp9*tmp9) / tmp6
    end if

    return sqrt(hh)
```

Both functions are mathematically the same (but using floating point numbers, the rounding errors may differ; so do not expect the results to be *exactly* the same when using floating-point math). I don't see any significant difference between the two. In particular, both need twelve multiplications and one division. The latter does need fewer additions/subtractions in the non-degenerate-triangle cases, so it might be a tiny bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

Given a triangle with vertices $A, B, C$. Its three altitudes intersect at the orthocenter $H$. Since $H$ lies in the plane holding the three vertices $A,B,C$.
There exists $3$ real numbers $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ such that

$$\vec{H} = \alpha \vec{A} + \beta \vec{B} + \gamma \vec{C}\quad\text{ and }\quad \alpha + \beta + \gamma = 1$$
The $3$-tuple $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ is called the [barycentric coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) of $H$. They can be computed using the side lengths $a,b,c$ of triangle alone. For the most common triangle centers, you can look up their barycentric coordinates from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Examples_of_special_points).
In particular, the orthocenter $H$ is given by

$$\alpha : \beta : \gamma =
\tan\angle A : \tan\angle B : \tan\angle C = 
\frac{1}{-a^2 + b^2 + c^2} : 
\frac{1}{a^2 - b^2 + c^2}  : 
\frac{1}{a^2 + b^2 - c^2}
$$
It is actually not that hard to deduce this formula ourselves. 
Since $H$ is lying on the altitude through $A$, $AH$ is perpendicular to $BC$. Notice

$$\vec{AH} = (\alpha \vec{A} + \beta\vec{B} + \gamma\vec{C}) - \vec{A}
 = \beta (\vec{B} - \vec{A}) + \gamma (\vec{C} - \vec{A} )
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\vec{BC} = \vec{C} - \vec{B}
$$
$AH \perp BC$ implies
$$ 
\beta (\vec{B} - \vec{A} )\cdot (\vec{C} - \vec{B}) + 
\gamma(\vec{C} - \vec{A} )\cdot (\vec{C} - \vec{B}) = 
- \beta c a\cos\angle B + \gamma b a\cos\angle C = 0
$$
Using the cosine rule for triangle, we find
$$\beta (a^2 + c^2 - b^2) = \gamma (a^2 + b^2 - c^2) 
\quad\iff\quad \beta : \gamma = \frac{1}{a^2-b^2+c^2} : \frac{1}{a^2+b^2-c^2}
$$
Other ratios like $\alpha : \beta$ and $\alpha : \gamma$ can be derived in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

This problem becomes simple if you think about the triangle as a collection of vectors. Consider a triangle with points A, B, and C in 3-D space. Assume that your base is defined by the vector BC. In order to find the point where the altitude intersects the base, we simply take the dot product of one of the sides, say AB, and the base vector, BC. This will yield a vector pointing to the intersection of the altitude and the base from point B on the triangle (as we essentially calculated the projection of the route to the apex of the triangle onto the base). Then, to convert back to standard coordinates, simply add the vector OA, (O is the origin) to the vector $\lambda$BC (the projection we calculated), and you will get a vector pointing to the base of the triangle where the altitude intersects with respect to the origin.

Comment: You lost me when stating to take the dot product of one of the sides and the base vector. Did you mean take the dot product between the base vector and the vector AB, and if so wouldn't that yield a scalar instead of a vector pointing to the intersection?

Comment: The resulting scalar, when applied to the base vector BC as a coefficient, yields the projection of AB onto BC. This $\lambda$ BC will now point from B to the point on BC that is closest to A, or, in other words, the place where a perpendicular line can be drawn from BC to A (where altitude intersects base). By adding the vector pointing from the origin to B, or OB , to the vector pointing from B to the intersection of the altitude and the base, or $\lambda$BC, we can get the vector pointing from the origin to the point where the altitude intersects the base.

Answer (score 0):

If $A,B,C$ are vertices, the vector $(\vec{AB}\times \vec{AC})\times \vec{BC}$ is in the plane $ABC$ and is perpendicular to $BC$. Write down the equation of line through $A$ parallel to this vector and find the point of intersection of this line with $BC$.